# How much does barometric pressure change over minutes?

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure, meteorology

I have to correct an ongoing experiment for atmospheric pressure. This means that during the experiment I must read a chip that measures barometric pressure. The question becomes one of how rapidly I have to read it in order to track changes in pressure due to variations in the weather.

This is ignoring changes in pressure due to people opening and closing doors etc, which is transient. What is the worst case I can expect? It is in an air conditioned lab, but I am not sure how much external wind might affect the answer. I also intend to ignore hurricanes and tornadoes on the grounds that the people inside will have better things to do than run the experiment.

I can measure to an accuracy of around a milliBar at up to 100 times a second

Comment: What time scales is your experiment running at? And how frequently are you sampling during your experiment? Could you just check the atmospheric pressure every time you take a data point in your experiment?

Comment: Ooo, and also, what region/country are you in? I've been through some pretty intense weather fronts where pressure will drop 100 hPa in under an hour. But where you are located may have events like that more or less frequently.

Comment: The experiments typically run for a few hours. I can take readings every 10mS if I need to, but it would be a real pain to do that. I was thinking once per second might be sufficient, or maybe even much longer.

Comment: The experiments will be run by people all across the world. However, I think we can rule out the polar circles.

Comment: Have you considered asking this questions on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/? They should have more people concerned with the time scales of atmospheric pressure changes.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data? I ask because the sample rate depends a lot on what frequency spectrum matters to you.  After all, if you have a large RAID drive handy, you can always sub-sample your data later on.

Comment: I need to track changes around 1 milliBar and correct results accordingly